# Plugin add_action and add_menu_page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, add-menu-page

I am using this code to make menu for my plugin. This works well.

My question is: what is the difference between including some php page and enqueue some scripts/styles in foo_admin_enqueue_scripts callback versus including them in add_menu_page/add_submenu_page callbacks?

```
function foo_admin_menu(){

    $menu = add_menu_page('Player manager', 'Foo Audio Player', FOO_CAPABILITY, 'foo_settings', 'foo_settings_page', 'dashicons-playlist-audio');

    $submenu = add_submenu_page('foo_settings', __('Foo Audio Player', FOO_TEXTDOMAIN), __('Settings', FOO_TEXTDOMAIN), FOO_CAPABILITY, 'foo_settings', 'foo_settings_page');   
    $submenu2 = add_submenu_page('foo_settings', __('Foo Audio Player', FOO_TEXTDOMAIN), __('Player manager', FOO_TEXTDOMAIN), FOO_CAPABILITY, 'foo_player_manager', 'foo_player_manager_page');    

    add_action( 'load-' . $menu, 'foo_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
    add_action( 'load-' . $submenu, 'foo_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
    add_action( 'load-' . $submenu2, 'foo_admin_enqueue_scripts' );

}

function foo_settings_page(){

    //1. include php page and script here?

    include("settings.php");

    wp_enqueue_script('enqueue something here')

}

function foo_player_manager_page(){

    ...

}

function foo_admin_enqueue_scripts() {

    //2. or include php page and script here?

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_media();

    wp_enqueue_style('foo', plugins_url('/css/admin.css', __FILE__));   
    wp_enqueue_script('foo', plugins_url('/js/admin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is the location where the style (`link`) or script tag be in the source, or whether the resource is loaded in `head` or the footer.

- With a `add_menu_page()`/`add_submenu_page()` callback like your `foo_settings_page()`, the style/script file would be loaded in the `body` (before the closing `body` tag), because the `head` has already been rendered by the time that the callback (`foo_settings_page()`) is called:

  ```html
  <body>
      ...
      the content of your plugin page (added through foo_settings_page())
      ...
      ...
      <!-- The style/script file would be loaded here, in the footer. -->
  </body>
  ```
- With your `foo_admin_enqueue_scripts()` which is a [`load-<page hook>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/) callback, the style/script file would be loaded in the `head` — but for a script, it could be in the footer; check the fifth parameter for [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

  ```html
  <head>
      ...
      <!-- The style/script file would be loaded here, unless if the *script* is set
      to be loaded in the footer. -->
      ...
  </head>
  ```

And I know there are certain cases where you need to load a style/script file right after a specific element is rendered on the page, but in most cases, style files should be loaded in `head` and script files in the footer — although in these modern days, scripts [may be put in the `head`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436411).